# Cant merge terminal's tabs (they all crash)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, 16.10

Im using Ubuntu 16.10, having this terminal structure:

- Window_1:{Tab_1, Tab_2}
- Window_2:{Tab_3, Tab_4}

When I click and drag Tab_1 then drop it to Window_2, instead of merging it with other Window_2's tabs, they all just crash.

Dropping Tab_1 to open space will open up Window_3 without a problem, it's just the merging that's the issue.